# How to sort an array based on another array

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing one application.In that i had two arrays with distance values and city names.I want to change the array values order into ascending based on distance values.This total process is worked for single distance values array by using sort descriptor.So my problem is how to change the city values array based on this distance values array order.The two arrays are arr1 with values 200,100,150 and arr2 with values ong,gdr,nlr

Comment: post your two array with value, so that one can able to understand the exact issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use the array sort or follow the link:
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
Hope this helpfull for you, if not then please share your code..

Answer (score 0):

using `NSComparisonResult` you can store the array with some object..

See the answer from this link which i used For Dictionary...

[sort-array-of-dicts-based-on-another-array-of-dicts](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/32641-sort-array-of-dicts-based-on-another-array-of-dicts.html)

May be you get some idea from this..

i hope this helpful to you....